# how to collect from a dict in python

Tags: python

in ruby:

```
hash = {'a' => {'abs' => 1}, 'b' => {'abs' => 4}, 'abc' => {'abs' => 6}}

DONT_COUNT_KEYS = ['abc']
sum = 0
hash.collect {|key,value| sum += value['abs'] unless DONT_COUNT_KEYS.include?(key)}
=> [1, 5, nil]
irb(main):007:0> sum
=> 5
```

I want to do the same in python in one line. what are my alternatives?
`each` is not for dict and `values()`doesn't exceptc a lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `sum` to do this

```
>>> h = {'a': {'abs':1},
         'b': {'abs':4},
         'c': {'abs':6},
         'd': {'abs':7},
         'e': {'abs':3}}
>>> DONT_COUNT_KEYS = 'abc'
>>> sum(value['abs'] for key, value in h.items() if key not in DONT_COUNT_KEYS)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in hash.items():
    sm += value['abs'] if key not in DONT_COUNT_KEYS else 0
```

or a list comprehension

```
[sm += value['abs'] for key, value in hash.items() if key not in DONT_COUNT_KEYS]
```

Comment: don't use sum as a variable name

Comment: On that note don't name the dictionary `hash`